# Nginx - Meaning of the ~ (tilde) in the location block of the nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

What is the meaning of the tilde after the location block in the nginx configuration?

for example

```
location ~ ^/download/(.*)$ {
  alias /home/website/files/$1;
}
```

What is the difference between with and without the  `"~"` ?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: A google search for "nginx tilde" gives the answer as the first result... Basic Nginx Configuration – Linode Library
https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic‎
Jul 26, 2013 - When a location directive is followed by a tilde (~), nginx performs a regular expression match. These matches are always case-sensitive.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The tilde instructs nginx to perform a case-sensitive regular expression match, instead of a straight string comparison.

More details in [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Additionally, `~*` modifier for case-insensitive reg exp matching and `^~` modifier to override possible matches elsewhere.